# Looping Over Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I realize that you cannot iterate over a Dictionary in C# and edit the underlying Dictionary as in the following example:

```
Dictionary<Resource, double> totalCost = new Dictionary<Resource, double>();
// Populate the Dictionary in here - (not showing code).    
foreach (Resource resource in totalCost.Keys)
{
     totalCost[resource] = 5;
}
```

One way I see to fix this is to make a List backed by the Dictionary's keys, like this:

```
Dictionary<Resource, double> totalCost = new Dictionary<Resource, double>();
// Populate the Dictionary in here - (not showing code).    
foreach (Resource resource in new List(totalCost.Keys))
{
     totalCost[resource] = 5;
}
```

Because I'm not editing the keys themselves, is there any reason that this should not be done or that it's bad to choose this as a solution.  (I realize if I was editing those keys, this could cause a lot of problems.)

Thank you.

**Edit:** Fixed my code example.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Doesn't the first piece of code work?

Comment: You are right.  Sorry about that - fixed it to show the problem I was trying to describe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your examples it doesn't look to me like you're editing the dictionary values (or keys)?

In general your solution looks fine, you could do it with a bit less code like this:

```
List<double> total = new List<double>();
foreach (AKeyObject key in aDictionary.Keys.ToList())
{
   for (int i = 0; i < aDictionary[key].Count; i++)
   {
      total[i] += aDictionary[key][i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to "ToList()" - still using Visual Studio 2005 (I'm guessing that is the reason).  But, thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: The ToList() is completely unnecessary anyway, "in aDictionary.Keys" will work just fine.

Comment: @Thorarin: if you leave out the ToList won't you get an exception about modifying the dictionary while enumerating it? (Hence the original question)

Answer (score 9):

You can loop over dictionaries with using [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) class.

```
Dictionary<string, string> d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in d1)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first piece of code looks fine to me - you're not editing the dictionary at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another more LINQ-esque version:

```
totalCost = totalCost
     .ToDictionary( kvp => kvp.Key, 5 );
```

Or, if 5 is not quite what you want :)

```
totalCost = totalCost
     .ToDictionary( kvp => kvp.Key, CalculateSomething(kvp.Value) );
```

(Note: this doesn't edit the underlying dictionary, instead it replaces it with a new one)